# How to resolve circular dependencies for projects when you want to remove duplicated code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, architecture, dependency-management, circular-dependency

Imagine you have the projects:

- Project *testUtils* that contains multiple test helper for your projects, all projects depends upon it.
- Project *mobile* that contains a **MobileService** and **MobileController** that depends upon *testUtils*
- Project 'customer' that contains a **CustomerService** and **CustomerController** that depends upon *mobile* and also *testUtils*

[image]

You create a **MobileServiceDouble implements IMobileService** in your *mobile* project that mocks the dependencies when testing your **MobileController**.

Also you want to create some tests for your **CustomerController**. This class depends upon **MobileController**. You decide not to mock **MobileController**. Instead you mock **MobileController**'s dependencies: **MobileService**. You create a second **MobileServiceDouble implements IMobileService**.

Your tests run fine and you decide to refactor duplicated code. So what's a good way to eliminate your duplicates?

You can't put your **MobileServiceDouble** into your *testutils* because otherwise you would have a circular dependency: *mobile* <--> *testutils*
Your MobileServiceDouble implements IMobileService that is located in *mobile*.

[image]

You could move the interface for your **MobileService**. But you don't want to have any production related interfaces in your *testutil* project.

[image]

I think it's a very minimal example for a real world issue in many systems and I'm sure there are great ideas how to resolve it.

What do you suggest?

**Update 1**:
I change the dependencies a bit to point out that it's not a problem that exists because I decided to use the real MobileController within my tests:

Imagine there are 3 packages:

- Project *ServiceRegistry*
- Project *Mobile* depends upon *ServiceRegistry* and *TestUtils*
- Project *Customer* depends upon *ServiceRegistry* and *TestUtils*
- Project *TestUtils*

*Mobile* and *Customer* are projects that have unit tests. So both want to mock for example the **ServiceRegistryManager** class of the *ServiceRegistry* project.

[image]

The projects Customer and Mobile creates ServiceRegistryManagerFakes. Same szenario: how to refactor this duplication? I move the fake class to *TestUtils*.

[image]

The result is a circular dependency. While I'm writing I'm thinking about a FakeTest project that could solve my issue:

[image]

At this point my dependencies and my projects increased. It feels very fragile because if my ServiceRegistry needs a Fake class then I need to create another *testFake2* project:

[image]

If the dependency of my new Project *TestFakes2* adds a dependency to a class that depends upon my *ServiceRegistry* then I will run again into issues.

[image]

So I always have to pay attention when I refactor my classes. I would have to create a lot of packages just because of circular dependencies. My target is to find a good best practice to minimize my effort regarding refactorings and project dependencies.

Looking for more ideas :).

Comment: I just had a similar problem and for me it was helpful to try to make an extra project that is not dependent of any other of my own projects (This enabled me to reference classes contained in that independent project from wherever I needed without having to worry about the dependencies). But when reading your question I'm not sure if you can apply the same technique to your problem... Just wanted to mention it.

Comment: TestUtils is some kind of extra package. It usually works when you only move multiple used classed. But as soon as you want to put mock classes in this extra package ( in my example *TestUtils* ) you run into circular dependencies because you need an interface from some package that also depends upon *TestUtils*.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are numerous code smells in your design and architecture.

1. testUtils, it seems your tests contain too complex logic if you need a separate module to store utils that are solely used in your tests. Do you have unit tests for your test utils?
2. > Also you want to create some tests for your CustomerController. This class depends upon MobileController. You decide not to mock MobileController. Instead you mock MobileController's dependencies: MobileService.

   Why you do not want to mock MobileController? Your `CustomerController` should use a test double of `MobileController`. It should not make the assumption that `MobileController` uses `MobileService`. This introduces a coupling between the `CustomerController` test and the mobile service. So if one day you change the implementation of `MobileController` (so that it will no longer use `MobileService`) without changing the contract of this class, tests in another module (`customer`) will start to fail.
3. Do your classes have a clearly defined contract? Do they align to the Single Responsibility Pattern?
4. Do you enforce separation of concerns? In other words, do you have clear rules what logic should be inside controllers and what inside services? If so, why would you use a controller from another controller?
5. Because you want to mock dependencies of a dependency I presume you write integration tests, which increase the feedback cycle time compared to unit tests (not to mention other cons).
6. Lastly, do you use Dependency Injection?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Firstly I want to point out that it's a simplified example. We should avoid talking about SOLID principles. We should focus on the issue. So I want to summarize your idea:

Mock your level 1 dependencies instead of mocking level 2 dependencies fixes the issue. 

I update my example to show that this solution does not solve the issue.